# Filter out NULL values in a Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL query where i pivot data. The problem i am having is that certain records in the pivoted data has null values for throughout. My query look something like this,

```
    select product, type, month, sum(case when variable = 'LY' then value end) as "LY",
    sum(case when variable = 'TY' then value end) as "TY",
    sum(case when variable = 'NY' then value end) as "NY"
    from tbl_sales
group by
product, type, month
```

My recordset then looks as follows,

```
Product  type  month  LY     TY    NY
AA1       2     1     20     30    40
AA2       4     1     30     50    60
AA3       4     1     NULL   NULL  NULL
AA4       3     1     NULL   NULL  NULL
```

This result is only a small part of the data and  have about 15 pivoted columns in total. The problem i am having is the last two records (Products AA3 and AA4 and i have got may of them. How can i filter these type of records out without any filtering on each column or a sum of the columns and then a filter?

Comment: add table structure info and data so we can clarify better.

Comment: add else condition to your case expressions: `then value else 0 end`

Comment: @Jason - also, please post the full query with the `group by` that is missing

Comment: @Jason - did it solve the problem? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a  unclear. If what you want is to remove records where you have a `null` value then add `where value <> null`. (but this will still result in records with `null` in some of the columns - if that column has no value..)

If you want to have a different default value that is not null, and not specify it in each column's `case when` then you can:

```
select product, type, month, sum(case when variable = 'LY' then value end) as "LY",
    sum(case when variable = 'TY' then value end) as "TY",
    sum(case when variable = 'NY' then value end) as "NY"
from (select product, type, month, variable, case when value is null then 0 else value end value from tbl_sales)
```

(but having it as 0 is kind of the same as having it as `null`)